# Instanciate a class inside a class NullPointerException

Tags: java, class, methods, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a nullPointerException error in the line `playlist1.firstSong = song;` below (9th line). Any ideas?

Playlist class:

```
public class Playlist { 
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
private Playlist playlist1=null, playlist2=null; 

private Song firstSong;
private Song secondSong;
private Song thirdSong;

public void setSong(Song song) { 
    if (song != null) {
        if (playlist1.firstSong == null) {
            playlist1.firstSong = song;
            System.out.println("The song has been added to the playlist.");
        }

        else if (playlist1.secondSong == null) {
            playlist1.secondSong = song;
            System.out.println("The song has been added to the playlist.");
        }

        else if (playlist1.thirdSong == null) {
            playlist1.thirdSong = song;
            System.out.println("The song has been added to the playlist.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This playlist is currently full with 3 songs. Please delete a song before attempting to add a new one.");
        }
    }
   }
```

addSongToPlaylist method:

```
private void addSongToPlaylist() { 
  if (songCount <=3) { 

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of the song you'd like to be added to the playlist."); 
    System.out.println("");

    database.Display();

    int songNumber; 
    songNumber = console.nextInt(); 

    switch (songNumber) { 
        case 1:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(1)); 
            break;
        case 2:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(2)); 
            break;
        case 3:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(3)); 
            break;
        case 4:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(4)); 
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid song number."); 
            break;
    }
    songCount++; 
  }
```

getSong method:

```
public Song getSong(int songNumber) { 
    if (songNumber == 1){ 
        return song1; 
    }
    else if (songNumber == 2){ 
        return song2; 
    }
    else if (songNumber == 3){ 
        return song3; 
    }
    else if (songNumber == 4){ /
        return song4; 
    }

    else {
        return song1; 
}
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm ... You got confused in your Playlist class. Your playlist actually stores 3 songs and that's it, **you don't need to use playlist1 & playlist2 .** 
Try to use this instead :

```
public class Playlist { 
private Song firstSong;
private Song secondSong;
private Song thirdSong;

public void setSong(Song song) { 
    if (song != null) {
        if (this.firstSong == null) {
            this.firstSong = song;
            System.out.println("The song has been added to the playlist.");
        }

        else if (this.secondSong == null) {
            this.secondSong = song;
            System.out.println("The song has been added to the playlist.");
        }

        else if (this.thirdSong == null) {
            this.thirdSong = song;
            System.out.println("The song has been added to the playlist.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This playlist is currently full with 3 songs. Please delete a song before attempting to add a new one.");
        }
    }
   }
```

Think that when you create an instance of Playlist, you can store 3 songs there, and that's it. If you want more playlist, you can create more.

But what if you wanted to store more than 3 songs ? For that, you can just refactor your code by using an `array` for example (Or any sort of storage, really.). Let's try with a Vector :

```
public class Playlist { 

private Vector<Song> songList;

public void setSong(Song song) { 
    if (song != null) {
             songList.add(song);
        }
   }
public Song getSong(int nb) {
    if (nb > 0 && nb < songList.size()) //We don't want to check the song #-1 or a song that would be out of bonds
         return songList.elementAT(nb);
}
 }
```

And there you have something a bit more cleaner. (There definitely are some typos in the code above, i can't really check them here but it serves as an example.)

As an answer for the comment :
If you want to use 2 playlist, it's fine, just use in your main :

```
   Playlist firstPlaylist;
   Playlist secondPlaylist;
```

Comment: @StephenC I'm uploading the code as we speak, wait a bit. For starters i wanted to show that this is more suitable than still using playlist1 & playlist2.

Comment: I need to have 2 playlists that the user can saves songs into though. So don't I need the playlist1 and playlist2 objects?

Comment: @Lachie You can have 2 instances of a same Class ! (that's the power of POO); i edited my code so you can see what i was talking about.

Answer (score 7):

because you did not initialize playlist object. Do the following,

Do this.

```
   private Playlist playlist1= new PlayList(), playlist2=new Playlist();
```

instead of

```
   private Playlist playlist1=null, playlist2=null;
```

**EDIT:**

```
class listMenu {
 // class that contains 3 playlists object. 

PlayList list1 = new Playlist(), list2 = new Playlist(), list3 = new PlayList(); 

addPlayList() {
  // whatever your logic for addition is.
}

}
```

The way you did a code is wrong because .

```
class PlayList {
 PlayList list1 = new PlayList(), list2 = new Playlist();
 private Song song1 = null;
 private Song song2 = null;
 private Song song3 = null; 

void setSong(Song song){
   list1.song1 = song; // you are storing song in  of list1.song field.
}
}
```

when to try to access the song, you will get NullPointerexception again

```
class Menu{
 void main(// ) {
  PlayList list = new PlayList();
  list.setSong(new Song()); 
  list.getSong1.name(); // throw exception, because song is stored in the member object not in itselt. 



}
}
```

I hope you get my point

Comment: @Mekap I don't think it's lazy, they answered the specific question the OP had. Perhaps there are other mistakes, but this answer fixes this problem.

Comment: actually you point-out right thing, +1 for that from me. 
He does not need playList object as well. 
I did'not noticed class name :p

Comment: @Lachie why you need PlayList Object in PlayList class? 
Makup point is valid. you should not do this, ad i'll recommend to accept makup answer

Comment: @MuneebNasir I changed it to what you posted and am now getting a java.lan.StackOverflowError. Any ideas?

Comment: @MuneebNasir I need the playlist object because I have 2 playlists, each of which store 3 songs.

Comment: what will happen, when to try to access Song from PlayListClass? it'll give you nullpointrexception, because you are storing song in another  object of playList. there is no pont to use playList object with in playList unless you have any special requirement

Comment: does not matter, you need to create 3 PlayList object, let me provide you the sample code.

Comment: @MuneebNasir Right, thanks, sample code would be really helpful!

Comment: The design of your answer is flawed by start since you want to fix a mistake's mistake's, and not the original issue.

Comment: i know - and that would lead him towards another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find where are you initializing the Playlist object. You are setting it as null, but never initializing it.

Anyway, it is better to check if the playList object is null and then set the vale for the field(firstSong).